# Is it clear where the school and playground are?

Tags: ellipsis, parallelism

According to my grammar book, when using **and** or **but** to link clauses, we can make the clauses parallel to each other and omit the repetitive parts. Therefore, in my version, the school must be at the end of **the road** and the playground must be to the north of **the road** because the sentence should be read as: Housing is to be built along both sides of the eastern road, a school <s>is to be built</s> at the end <s>of the eastern road</s> and a playground <s>is to be built</s> to the north <s>of the eastern road</s>. Is this correct?

> Housing is to be built along both sides of the eastern road, a school
> at the end, and a playground to the north. (Mine)

A freelancer who is a native speaker wrote me the version below. I think in his version, it is unclear where the school and playground are. His three clauses are not parallel so it's unclear what are omitted. What do you think?

> The area around the eastern road is to be for housing, a school at the
> end, and a playground to the north. (Freelancer's)

Comment: Yours is superior. The freelancer's isn't grammatical. It should read "... **with** a school at the end (of the road?) and a playground to the north."

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Is my reasoning correct? Is my version an ellipsis of this: Housing is to be built along both sides of the eastern road, a school <is to be built> at the end <of the eastern road> and a playground <is to be built> to the north <of the eastern road>.

Comment: Yes, your ellipses are correct.   But the actual situation direction-wise isn't all that clear, though it may be just an example of ellipsis and not reflect any reality.

Comment: You say *when using and or but to link clauses,* but in your first example it would be perfectly natural (arguably, *better*) not to include the word ***and*** there at all: *... along both sides of the eastern road; a school at the end, a playground to the north.* It's a bit ugly switching from "the end" to "to the north", though. Better to use "the other end", or start with "to the South"

Comment: Your version is quite good. But, it's not like there will be incorrect construction based on your sentence alone. There will be blueprints, authorizations, deposit payments and such.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. Can I still omit the second verb when it's different from the first verb? For example, can I omit **are to be** when the first clause uses **is to be**? To the south of the road is to be a school and to the north **are to be** shops.